# Multiple selectize - populate with value from database

Tags: javascript, php, select, selectize.js

In one page I have multiple selectize select with same name.
I can`t populate the selectize with value from database. (At the beginning the select is empty because I have 40k values in database).

This is a javascript code: (work only when I search in select)

```
$('.nume_medicament').selectize({
      valueField: 'nume_medicament',
      labelField: 'nume_medicament',
      searchField: 'nume_medicament',
      options: [],
      create: false,
      render: {
          
        option: function(item, escape) {
            return '<option datacod="'+item.cod_medicament+'" value="'+item.id_medicament+'">'+item.nume_medicament+'</option>';
        },
      },    
      load: function(query, callback) {
        if (!query.length) return callback();
        $.ajax({
          url: site_url + "medicmed/get_medicamente_by_search",
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
            name: query,
          },
          error: function() {
            callback();
          },
          success: function(res) {
            callback(res);  
          }
        });
      },        
    });
```

And this is html file:

```
<select name="nume_medicament" class="nume_medicament checkmed selectizedefault">
    <option selected datacod="<?=$pm->cod_medicament?>" value="<?=$pm->id_medicament?>"><?=$pm->nume_medicament?></option>  
</select>
```

A want to assign the option when I enter in the page.

Thank you!!